gitlab runner skipping checkout even with GIT_CHECKOUT set to true
I have gitlab-runner 17.1.0. My .gitlab-ci.yml file has GIT_CHECKOUT: true, but gitlab still skips checkout. Any idea why?
This excerpt from log shows the problem:
Running with gitlab-runner 17.1.0 (fe451d5a)
  on xxxxxx xxxxx, system ID: xxxxx
Resolving secrets
Preparing the "shell" executor
00:00
Using Shell (bash) executor...
Preparing environment
00:00
Running on xxxxx...
Getting source from Git repository
00:00
Skipping Git repository setup
Skipping Git checkout
Skipping Git submodules setup
Executing "step_script" stage of the job script
00:01
$ echo $GIT_CHECKOUT
true
$ echo $GIT_STRATEGY
none

I also have no idea where GIT_STRATEGY is being set as my CI/CD settings have this:

While I explicitly set GIT_CHECKOUT to true in my .gitlab-ci.yml file, I do not set GIT_STRATEGY anywhere.

This pipeline was invoked as a child pipeline of another pipeline, and the parent pipeline had GIT_STRATEGY: none in the .gitlab-ci.yml file. This variable was propagated down to the child pipeline.
